# Compare two collections in MongoDb and remove common

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have three collections in MongoDB

1. achievements
2. students
3. student_achievements

`achievements` is a list of achievements a students can achieve in an academic year while
`students` collections hold data list of students in the school.
`student_achievements` holds documents where each documents contains studentId & achievementId.

I have an interface where i use `select2` multiselect to allocate one or more  achievements from `achievements` to students from `students` and save it to their collection `student_achievements`, right now to do this i populate `select2` with available achievements from database. I have also made an arrangement where if a student is being allocated same achievement again the system throws an error.

**what i am trying to achieve is** if an achievement is allocated to student that shouldn't be available in the list or removed while fetching the list w.r.t student id,

what function in mongodb or its aggregate framework can i use to achieve this i.e to compare to collections and remove out the common.

Comment: please share your code! Thx

Comment: what code should i share ? i can share database models.

Comment: and i am not asking for any code here just a hint on going forward

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your data-structure could be made different to make the problem easier to solve. MongoDB is a NoSQL schemaless store, don't try to make it be like a relational database.

Perhaps we could do something like this:

```
var StudentSchmea = new Schema({
    name: String,
    achievements: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Achivement' }]
});
```

Then you can do something like this which will only add the value if it is unique to the achievements array:

```
db.student.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: { achievements: <achivement id> } }
)
```

If you are using something like Mongoose you can also write your own middleware to remove orphaned docs:

```
AchivementSchema.post('remove', function(next) {
    // Remove all references to achievements in Student schema
});
```

Also, if you need to verify that the achievement exists before adding it to the set, you can do a `findOne` query before updating/inserting to verify.

Even with the post remove hook in place, there are certain cases where you will end up with orphaned relationships potentially. The best thing to do for those situations is to have a regularly run cron task to to do cleanup when needed. These are some of the tradeoffs you encounter when using a NoSQL store.